# Port already in use VScode terminal

Tags: express, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Often getting error that port already in use while using VScode terminal to run my server with debugger. I was getting into the same situation while I was working on React projects, now I am on Express.js. Taking the same steps, to start debugging, going to package.json, and run debug script `nodemon index.js`

Comment: well the obvious questions are - which port and who is using it? What platform - mac, linux, windows?

Comment: I had to kill extra terminals, that located in bottom right corner of VSCode, when I work sometimes I spin up several of them, when switching between debugging mode and debugging test cases